# Multithreading vector of threads c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, sfml

I am trying to expand my knowledge of threading in c++. I have read through a few of the basic tutorials on threading as well as mutex and am trying to have a for loop that runs through a vector and runs function with each part of it. For some reason a few of the functions don't get errors but most do.

```cpp
        while (!(threadVecSize + 1) >= maxThreads)
        {
            std::thread thread1;
            thread1 = thread(WindowArray[i]->setPosition(Gravity(KeyArray[i], WindowArray[i]))); //(void) is not a argument exsepted by std::thread::thread
             thread1 = thread(WindowArray[i]->setPosition, Gravity(KeyArray[i], WindowArray[i])); //<error-type>, sf::Vector2i is not a argument exsepted by std::thread::thread
            thread1.join;
        }
```

set position changes the windows position and takes a vector2i
This is my class for keys

```cpp
class NewKey {
public:
    sf::Image Img;
    sf::Texture Tex;
    sf::Sprite Sprite;
    sf::Vector2i Velocity;
    sf::Vector2i Acceleration;
};
```

Window Array is a vector of sfml RenderWindows Everything in the step windows function is for managing my array of windows. I know that all that code works because I had it functioning before trying to add threading to help smooth it out.

The Errors

```
No instance of constructor std::thread::thread matches the argument list
```

My Variables

```
    sf::Vector2i Gravity(MakeKey::NewKey& Key, unique_ptr <sf::RenderWindow>& window);
vector <NewKey> KeyArray;
vector <unique_ptr <sf::RenderWindow>> WindowArray;
vector <thread> threadVec;
int threadVecSize = threadVec.size();
unsigned maxThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
```

Comment: Can you make a minimum (not) working example? There's not enough to go on from what you've posted. It's pretty likely it's the way you're constructing threads like this isnt' valid though: thread(WindowArray[i]->clear, sf::Color::Transparent);

Comment: Please delete your old question if you want this to be the active one. What version of SFML are you using?

Comment: This line `threadVec[currentThread] = thread(WindowArray[i]->setActive(true)); //works` shouldn't work. There's no `thread` constructor that takes a `bool` variable.

Comment: in `const int threadVecSize = threadVec.size();`, `threadVecSize` will always be 0. That's certainly not what you want?

Comment: If you run your `while` loop more than once, you'll deadlock since you're trying to lock the `mutex` more than once. If you run your `while` loop zero times, you'll have undefined behavior when you try to unlock the currently unlocked mutex.

Comment: I am using sfml 5.1. I am trying to have the thread go through and run the voids. No thats not what I intended. I guess that shouldn't be const should it. Evidently i'm also using mutex honorably wrong but i can figure that one out on my own for now don't worry about it. Ill also update the code to remove mutex. Thanks.

Comment: `mutex1.lock;` is a no-op expression.  You aren't actually invoking the function itself. For that you'd need to invoke `mutex1.lock()`.  That is parentheses matter.  Aside from that, mutexes need to be shared with threads to matter anyway.  I don't see that going on here.

Comment: `threadVec[currentThread].join;` is a no-op as well. You have to call the function. Also, what the point of creating a thread only to wait for it to finish?

Comment: I know you're excited, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of Stack Overflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit.

Comment: lol ok i will,,